Play .MP3 file located in server folder on MySQL echo output
I currently have a form where users upload details including an MP3 file. Details are stored on a MySQL DB and the MP3 file is stored in my server folder /orgs/user/uploads (URL domain.com/orgs/user/uploads) with the MP3 file name stored in the DB.
I'm trying to output it using the below script and seem to have the audio player function working fine, however for the life of me can't figure out how to call the file location from the server in it therefore it's currently displaying the audio controls with no audio.
  if ($row ['approved'] == "1" && $row  ['service'] == "Army" )
{
    
      echo "<div class='speech-bubble'>";
       echo "<p> <strong>" . $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['initial'] .  "</strong></p>"; // Replace 'column_name' with the actual column name from your table
           echo "<p>" . $row['service'] . "</p>"; 
           echo "<p>" . $row['year'] . "</p>"; 
           echo "<p>" . $row['story_text'] . "</p>"; 
           echo '<audio controls>';
           echo '<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode($row['name']).'">';
           echo '</audio>';

Placed different versions of the server path and URL in "script src" section

If MP3 file is stored in my server folder then base64_encode($row['name']) is not what you need. You'd be encoding a name, not the binary data. You'd need to do file_get_contents I believe... You also don't need an echo per line. You can concatenate across lines, or have the string expand lines.

Thanks so much for the input.  I will look into file_get_contents commands

Are you sure this problem is related to MySQL itself? Also, keep in mind that you should escape the content stored in your database on echoing it, to avoid that anybody injects HTML into your markup

Are you really asking how to build a valid URL to the mp3 file location?

Audio files can be large and mp3 is a lossy format specifically designed to compress files as much as possible. If you encode it as Base64 (plain text) you kind of defeat the purpose, and if you embed it in the HTML document you're going to crash someone's browser sooner or later.

you have to first get the content of the file and then use it . also you can check if file exists provided you have saved only file name in table

$folder= "/orgs/user/uploads/"; // upload folder

if ($row ['approved'] == "1" && $row  ['service'] == "Army" ){

   if(file_exists($folder.$row['name']) ){ // check for file
 
      $file = file_get_contents($folder.$row['name']); // get file contents

      echo "<div class='speech-bubble'>";
       echo "<p> <strong>" . $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['initial'] .  "</strong></p>"; // Replace 'column_name' with the actual column name from your table
           echo "<p>" . $row['service'] . "</p>"; 
           echo "<p>" . $row['year'] . "</p>"; 
           echo "<p>" . $row['story_text'] . "</p>"; 
           echo '<audio controls>';
           echo '<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode($file).'">';
           echo '</audio>';
   } // if file
}// if approved


your can directly call file from url also like below provided you have saved only file name in table

  $url ="https://example.com/orgs/user/uploads/";
  $folder= "/orgs/user/uploads/"; // upload folder

  if ($row ['approved'] == "1" && $row  ['service'] == "Army" ){

   if(file_exists($folder.$row['name']) ){ // check for file
 
      echo "<div class='speech-bubble'>";
       echo "<p> <strong>" . $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['initial'] .  "</strong></p>"; // Replace 'column_name' with the actual column name from your table
           echo "<p>" . $row['service'] . "</p>"; 
           echo "<p>" . $row['year'] . "</p>"; 
           echo "<p>" . $row['story_text'] . "</p>"; 
           echo '<audio controls>';
           echo '<source src="'.$url.$row['name'].'">';
           echo '</audio>';
   } // if file
}// if approved

